# ansible failed_when string contains "fail" or "error" or "fault" case insensitive

Tags: regex, ansible, jinja2, powershell-4.0

Currently I am using `failed_when: "'failed' in result|lower or 'error' in result|lower or 'fault' in result|lower"` to catch failure condition of an ansible task. What's the best way of writing this condition checking if any of the `failed/error/fault` is in the returned `win_shell` command returned status string?

Answer (score 3):

> What's the best way of writing this condition checking if any of the `failed/error/fault` is in the returned win_shell command returned status string?

First thing: write correct yaml. Your initial problem is simple syntax:

```yaml
# This a yaml key containing a simple value
a_key: a value

# This is the same value but the string is optionally quoted
other_key: "a value"

# But if you use quotes the string stops at the closing quote
# so the below will fire a parsing error
error_key: "a quoted string" and some garbage chars

# In this case you need disambiguation using other quotes,
# escaping, scalar blocks....
corrected_key1: '"a quoted string" and some garbage chars'
corrected_key2: "\"a quoted string\" and some garbage chars"
corrected_key3: >
  "a quoted string" and some garbage chars
# non exhaustive list
```

As a first fix, we can simply rewrite your condition as follows:

```yaml
failed_when: '"failed" in result|lower or "error" in result|lower or "fault" in result|lower'
```

But a better approach to avoid repeating the search term and the filter to transform it lower case for every single case you want to test would be to use a `regex` test:

```yaml
failed_when: result is regex('^.*(failed|error|fault).*$', ignorecase=true)
```

There might be even "nicer" ways to write this condition depending on the exact pattern of your error messages.

Comment: Single-quoted string within the parent double-quoted string is also a way of disambiguation: `corrected_key1: "'a quoted string' and some garbage chars"`

Comment: This is why I indicated `# non exhaustive list`. That one would do it as well => `'''a quoted string'' and some garbage'`, and we are not yet over... for more you can have a look at https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/ and https://yaml-multiline.info/ as two documentation examples.